# What does differentiation of B-cell mean?

Tags: immunology

Does differentiation of B lymphocytes mean the formation of plasma cells and memory cells by matured B lymphocytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immature B lymphocytes mature *into* either plasma cells or memory cells. If a B cell is mature, that means it's already a memory or plasma cell.

Comment: Could you cite some references?